# FacebookLogin: my android applicationId is null

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I try to click the FacebookSDK login button and get an error

that my `applicaitonId` is null.

how can I init it properly?

```
            Session currentSession = sessionTracker.getSession();
            if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
                sessionTracker.setSession(null);
                Session session = new Session.Builder(context).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                currentSession = session;
            }
```

Comment: A good answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156856/android-facebook-applicationid-cannot-be-null).

Comment: Refer the last section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include below line of code in you manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

and

```
<string name="app_id">Your Facebook App Id</string>
```

in res/values/strings.xml