# Gradle giving back wrong resValue, but not always

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have fields which declared in `build.gradle` like:

```
defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "reg_id", "111111111111"
        resValue "string", "os", "2"
    }
```

Then I use them in code like:

```
msg = "project id from "  + context.getString(R.string.reg_id) + " ... " + context.getString(R.string.os);
```

But in logs I getting:

```
project id from -558038585 ... 2
```

gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

Should I fire issue to google or there is something which I'm not understand?

**EDIT:**

I fired [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=88492&thanks=88492&ts=1419494610), please give a star to speed up fix

Comment: Looks like you need to report about it. it's quite strange behavior, for example, `resValue "string", "reg_id", "1111111111"` will be shown as `project id from 1111111111 ... 2`

Comment: Please add link to created issue

Comment: @gio OK! Link provided.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "reg_id", '"1111111111111"'
        resValue "string", "os", '"2"'
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519661/4074312